# Open a file without extension with QLPreviewController or UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction, qlpreviewcontroller

Is there a way to open a file with QLPreviewController or UIDocumentInteractionController, knowing its UTI, but without a file extension in the NSURL? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10):

I've just found another way to deal with it. Implement an item with the following properties:

```
@interface QuickLookPreviewItem : NSObject <QLPreviewItem>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *uti;
@end

@implementation QuickLookPreviewItem
- (NSString *)previewItemTitle { return self.title; }
- (NSURL *)previewItemURL { return self.url; }
- (NSString *)previewItemContentType { return self.uti; }
@end
```

Though it's not clear that it works that way in the documentation.

Comment: it's work like a charm, but it's undocumented, so its supposed to be a private API... probably because UTI standard it's just an Apple thing, it's not a standard:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

Comment: This also works for Swift 3. Since it's private API, would it pass an app store review?

Answer (score 0):

add the file extension to the path while quick-looking it :)
before push => add extension
after pop => remove it again